# sql query writing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to fill in PurchaseOrders and PurchaseOrder details tables in my db with the data from a file which I already have in my staging table successfully. Task
is to get ST columns values to specific respective destination table(PurchaseOrders and PurchaseOrderDetails)

query so far(sqlserver 2014 & 2012)
:

```
insert into PurchaseOrders( 
     NameId, 
     LocationId, 
     VendorId, 
     PurchaseOrderDate, 
     PurchaseOrderSerialNo, 
     PurchaseOrderCreatBy, 
     PurchaseOrderCreateOn, 
     ModBy, 
     ModOn
 ) 
 select 
     '10', 
     Locations.Id, 
     cast (VENDOR as int), 
     cast(PO_DATE as date), 
     (select distinct cast(PurchaseOrderNUMBER as int) from StagingTable), 
     'name', 
     getdate(), 
     NULL, 
     NULL 
 from 
     [dbo].[StagingTable] ST
          join Locations  on Locations.Code = ST.LOCATION 
          join Vendor   on Vendor.Code = ST.VENDOR
```

on running this I get following, having nothing in destination tables:

```
(0 row(s) affected)
```

Same for PurchaseOrderDetails is rqd ?

Comment: Run just the select statement and figure out why you are getting 0 rows. Maybe the location codes or vendor codes aren't matching.

Comment: Also, try inserting without you select statement in you subquery... And I think your whole select needs to be in parenthesis indicating what values you are inserting.

Comment: Thanks for the replies... i am on it with independent runs! hoping for a success!

Comment: sorry for the late response, my appologies in this regard!

Answer (score 0):

Following is working for me, as far as the results r concerned!

```
if exists (select OrdersSerialNo FROM PurchaseOrders PO join [dbo].[StagingTable] ST on PO.OrdersSerialNo  != ST.PurchaseOrder_NUMBER)

begin

insert into PurchaseOrders( 
     NameId, 
     LocationId, 
     VendorId, 
     PurchaseOrderDate, 
     PurchaseOrderSerialNo, 
     PurchaseOrderCreatBy, 
     PurchaseOrderCreateOn, 
     ModBy, 
     ModOn
 ) 

 select 
     @IdName, 
     Locations.Id, 
     cast (VENDOR as int), 
     cast(PO_DATE as date), 
     (select distinct cast(PurchaseOrderNUMBER as int) from [dbo].[StagingTable]), 
     'name', 
     getdate(), 
     NULL, 
     NULL 

 from 
     [dbo].[StagingTable] ST

inner join PurchaseOrders PO on PO.OrdersSerialNo  != ST.PurchaseOrder_NUMBER

inner join Products  on Products.Code = ST.ITEMCode 

inner join Locations  on Locations.Code = ST.LOCATION 

where   isnumeric(VENDOR) = 1 and isnumeric(PO_NUMBER) = 1 and isdate(PO_DATE) = 1 
)
end
```

apologies for the late response!